# Entity Framework and DbContext - Object Tracking

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am a bit confused on the usage of DbContext in Entity Framework. Here's the scenario I'm confused about.

- I use a linq query from the dbcontext to get data. Something like:

  ```
  List<Transactions> transactions = DefaultContext.Transactions.ToList();
  ```
- Then I update a column in one of the transactions returned in that query directly in the database.
- Then I call again:

  ```
  List<Transactions> transactions = DefaultContext.Transactions.ToList();
  ```

When the list returns back this time, it doesn't reflect the updates/changes I made when running the update statement, unless I loop through all my transactions and Reload them:

```
foreach (DbEntityEntry<Transactions> item in DefaultContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<Transactions>())
{
    DefaultContext.Entry<Transactions>(item.Entity).Reload();
}
```

Is this normal behavior? I assume that on my initial query, they are attached to the object context. Then when I query the second time, it doesn't make a trip to the database, and just pulls out the entities from the object context, unless I clear/detach or individually reload all of the entities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is normal and in case of DbContext API fixed behaviour because from some very strange reason neither `DbSet` or `DbQuery` expose `MergeOption` property. In case of ObjectContext API you can set the behaviour by `MergeOption` exposed on `ObjectSet` and `ObjectQuery`. So if you want to refresh values from database (and lose your changes) you can do:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<Transactions> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<Transactions>();
set.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
List<Transactions> transactions = set.ToList();
```

If you just want to refresh transactions but you don't want to lose your changes you can use `MergeOption.PreserveChanges` instead.

Comment: I need to filter some of the data returned. I was using a .Where(... before, however now that I'm using ObjectContext, it's not aware of my entity classes. How do I filter the data now on the query though? I don't want to return back the entire result.

Comment: What you mean by "it's not aware of my entity classes". You can write same linq query with ObjectContext as you did with DbContext.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the `MergeOption` of the `DefaultContext.Transactions` query. The default value, `AppendOnly`, [won't overwrite objects already in your context.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx) You can change this to `OverwriteChanges` to get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As I'm using DbContext, my queries aren't of type ObjectQuery though. So I can't cast a query like var query = Defaultcontext.Transactions; to ((ObjectQuery)query).MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges; Do I need to use a linq style query instead?

Answer (score 1):

Related to the above, this is where I landed when I had this same error.  But I wanted in my case to set **Merge Option** to **No Tracking**.  I ran into this when I had an excel export method that was attempting to turn off object tracking of an IQueryable.  Moving through lots of data that I wasn't going to be changing, I didn't need any change tracking.

A line of code similar to the below would fail on attempting to cast some IQueryables to class ObjectQuery (but succeed on others.)

```
var y = ((ObjectQuery)query).MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

Instead, I replaced this with usage of **AsNoTracking**

```
query = query.AsNoTracking();
```

Relating back to the original question, this would be potentially like the below, Extention method on DBQuery added in **System.Data.Entity**

```
List<Transactions> transactions = DefaultContext.Transactions.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Semi-Related Article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx